# Reorder tmux windows

Tags: tmux

How can I efficiently reorder windows in tmux?  For example, having this set of windows:

```
0:zsh  1:elinks  2:mutt  3:irssi  4:emacs  5:rss  6:htop
```

What would I have to do to move `rss` to between `elinks` and `mutt`, ending up with:

```
0:zsh  1:elinks  2:rss  3:mutt  4:irssi  5:emacs  6:htop
```

I know how to use `move-window` to move a window to a yet-unused index, and I could use a series of them to achieve this—but, obviously, this is very tedious.

Comment: This SU Q&A shows what you're asking for: http://superuser.com/questions/343572/how-do-i-reorder-tmux-windows

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`swap-window` can help you:

```
swap-window -t -1
```

It moves current window to the left by one position.

From [man tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1):

```
swap-window [-d] [-s src-window] [-t dst-window]
             (alias: swapw)
This is similar to link-window, except the source and destination windows are swapped. 
It is an error if no window exists at src-window.
```

You can bind it to a key:

```
bind-key -n S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n S-Right swap-window -t +1
```

Then you can use `Shift+Left` and `Shift+Right` to change current window position.

Comment: But I would still have to do a series of `swap-window` commands (three for the example case)—correct?

Comment: @igor: Yes. Another way, you can do `swap-window -s 2 -t 5`. This swap window number 2 with window number 5.

Comment: Right—but I want to keep the order of all other windows intact, so a ‘simple’ swapping of windows #2 and #5 doesn’t do it for me.  I already was aware of the `swap-window` command, but didn’t know about the `-`/`+` prefixes to target the previous/next window.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525770/12497 for addressing the changed behavior of `swap-window` in newer tmux versions

Comment: In new tmux versions, add the `-d` option for a more intuitive behavior where you keep focus on the swapped window. E.g. `swap-window -d -t -1`

Answer (score 14):

The accepted and highly upvoted answer is correct, though behavior in recent tmux versions sees the swap-window command not keep you on the same window. So it works rather unintuitively, your active window will get swapped in that direction but you will stay put in the same slot!

To fix that issue, simply augment the bind to follow it. For example from my tmux config:

```
bind -n C-S-Left { swap-window -t -1; previous-window }
bind -n C-S-Right { swap-window -t +1; next-window }
```

Comment: A better way is to use `-d` to restore the old intuitive behavior. E.g. `swap-window -d -t -1`. Source: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1879

Answer (score 3):

## Out-of-the-box way (Tmux 3.0+)

There is this [display-menu](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#display-menu) feature in changes from [v2.9 to v3.0](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES?plain=1#L812).

In Tmux, you can now use <kbd>(Prefix) <</kbd> to trigger a floating box, where you can control to swap the current window with others as below.

[image: display-menu-demo]

---

Remarks:

- The Prefix by default is <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>
- <kbd>(Prefix) ></kbd> will trigger a floating box with [other features](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#display-popup) too, such as splitting and zoom.

---

<strike>I accidentally stumbled upon the shortcut of using `(Prefix) <` to trigger a floating box, where you can control to swap the current window with others.</strike>

<strike>Not sure if it is a new feature since I couldn't find it in any documentation while having all plugins disabled. But it helped me to reorder the windows.</strike>

Thank you for quoting the documentation by @KamilMaciorowski

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution wrapped in bash function.

```
list=$(tmux lsw -F '#I');                           # for shift left, could be moved inside function
list=$(tmux lsw -F '#I'); list=$(echo $list|rev);   # for shift right, list reversed
shift_tmux_window_range() {  # depend on `list`
    local started=0 beg=$1 end=$2
    for i in $list; do
        if (($i == $beg)); then
            started=1; h=$beg; tmux linkw -s $beg && tmux unlinkw -t $beg;
        elif (($i == $end)); then
            tmux movew -d -s $i -t $h; tmux movew -d -t $end; break;
        elif [ $started = 1 ]; then
            tmux movew -d -s $i -t $h; h=$i;
        fi;
    done
}

shift_tmux_window_range 5 2
```

Bonus: stay in the same window if current active window not affected.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `tmux` is version 1.7 or higher

```
move-window -r
```

or

```
set-option -g renumber-windows on
```

in `.tmux.conf` for automatically doing, in future.